# Does distance to the boundary equal distance to the complement?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space, $U$ an open subset and $x \in U$.

Is it true that if $d(x, X\setminus U)<\epsilon$ then $d(x, Bd U)< \epsilon$?

It would be so if $d(x, X\setminus U)=d(x, Bd U)$. Is this true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.

Let $X=\Bbb R\times\{0,1\}$ with the induced metric as subsapce of $\Bbb R^2$.
Let $U=(0,\infty)\times \{0\}$. Then $x=(42,0)\in U$ has distance $1$ to the complement, but distance $42$ to the boundary.